# JQuery Import successful, but doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the bare bones of what will eventually become a webpage, and am running it locally for the time being with XXAMP control panel.

My plugin is successfully linking all of the necessary files and importing the outside stuff, but JQuery does not seem to work in my javascript file. Can someone help me out?

Here are my imports:

```
    <!-- Most Recent JQuery -->
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <!-- JQuery Box Shadown Plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.shadow-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
    <!-- Most Recent Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Most Recent Bootsrap -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Most Recent Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Fancybox for Images/Iframes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <!-- Fancybox JS -->
    <script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

And here is the javascript file (the first is suppose to do what I want, the others are just for test cases):

```
$('#openIcon').hover(function(){
    console.log("Hovered");
    $('#openIcon').animate({
        boxShadow: "2px, 2px, 5px, #FFFFFF"
    }, 100, "linear");
});

$('#openIcon').click(function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});

$('#openIcon').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("Entered");
});

$('#openIcon').mouseleave(function(){
    console.log("Left");
});
```

EDIT: I already found a post on this site about the same type of problem, where the guy didn't have the https: before the two slashes. This WAS a problem that I had, but have since fixed and it has made no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding $( document ).ready() :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#openIcon').hover(function(){
    console.log("Hovered");
    $('#openIcon').animate({
        boxShadow: "2px, 2px, 5px, #FFFFFF"
    }, 100, "linear");
});

$('#openIcon').click(function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});

$('#openIcon').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("Entered");
});

$('#openIcon').mouseleave(function(){
    console.log("Left");
});

});
```